# @Annotation before inline Block { }

Tags: java, annotations

Is there anz possiblity to design something like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface ParallelBlock {
}
```

So the result could be:

```
public void method(){
    //some code
    @ParallelBlock {
        //some more code
    }
}
```

Or is the only possibility something like preprocessing?

Comment: What is the intended meaning of `@ParallelBlock`? Run some code multiple times in parallel?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ElementType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html) enum as you've used in your code clarifies this

```
ANNOTATION_TYPE  Annotation type declaration
CONSTRUCTOR      Constructor declaration
FIELD            Field declaration (includes enum constants)
LOCAL_VARIABLE   Local variable declaration
METHOD           Method declaration
MODULE           Module declaration.
PACKAGE          Package declaration
PARAMETER        Formal parameter declaration
TYPE             Class, interface (including annotation type), or enum declaration
TYPE_PARAMETER   Type parameter declaration
TYPE_USE         Use of a type
```

and there is none that `Target`s a block of code for that matter.

A cleaner way for that sake would be *abstracting that block of code out in a method* and then using the type `METHOD` for annotating that method.